# Error ERRORSQLSTATE[23000] al insertar datos en MariaDB

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Holas amigos, estoy intentando insertar datos a mi base de datos, pero me sale el siguiente error.

> ERRORSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`entradas`, CONSTRAINT `entradas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

esta es mi base de datos con sus tablas relacionadas

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    fecha_registro DATETIME NOT NULL,
    activo TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE entradas (
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    autor_id INT NOT NULL,
    titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
    activa TINYINT NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY(id),  
        FOREIGN KEY(autor_id)
            REFERENCES usuarios(id) 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE 
                ON DELETE RESTRICT 
);
CREATE TABLE comentarios (
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    autor_id INT NOT NULL,
    entrada_id INT NOT NULL,
    titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    texto TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
     FOREIGN KEY(autor_id)
        REFERENCES usuarios(id) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE 
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
        FOREIGN KEY(entrada_id) 
        REFERENCES entradas(id) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE 
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que en los datos que insertas el `autor_id` no existe en la tabla de `usuarios`, o tal vez es `null`, verifica que esos `id` existan para poder insertarlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error se presenta porque

- no puedes ingresar un valor en el campo **`autor_id`** de la tabla **`entradas`** si ese dato no se encuentra en la tabla **`usuarios`** (en su campo **`id`**)

Comment: puede darme un ejemplo lustrativo de como hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto de base de datos.

Comment: Claro que sí. Primero debes hacer el insert en usuarios así: `insert into usuarios (nombre, email, password, fecha_registro, activo) values ('Juan', 'Juan@gmail.com', 'juan123', NOW(), 1)` y **luego** de este insert haces el insert en la tabla entradas: `insert into entradas(autor_id, titulo, texto, fecha, activa) values (1, 'Mi Titulo, 'todo el texto', NOW(), 1)`

Comment: Bien, muchas gracias amigo por tu ayuda, me sirvió mucho.